# display each set of 3 numbers on a new line separated by commas

Tags: javascript

I need a JavaScript code that generates 3 numbers between 1 and 10 one hundred times.It should display each set of 3 numbers on a new line separated by commas, and also display the total number of times the generated numbers were equal to 7 (also on
a separate line).
 An example output should be formatted as follows:
Number set 1 is: 10,7,8
Number set 2 is: 5,1,7 
The code I have for some reason is not working

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Day 3 - Example 7</title>
</head
<body>

 <script language="javascript">
   // count number of times seven was generated
   var i,num,n,num1,num2,cnt=0;
   n=100;
   for( i=1; i<=n; i++){
       num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
       num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
       num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
       document.write("Number Set " +i+ is + num,+ num1, +num2);

       if (num == 7) {
           cnt++;
      > }
   }
   document.write("<br>Total number of Sevens: " + cnt);

 </script>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: can you specify the exact problem you're having? also, the word "is" within the document.write is not defined, is it? if so you should encapsulate that inside quotes and the plus symbol after the commas are not necessary.

Comment: @Pineda the commas are fine, it's just the "is" and the plus( + ) symbols after the commas OP has to remove.

Comment: You'll have to check for `num1 === 7` and `num2 === 7` as well!

Comment: Please make the title descriptive of the problem. As written it is of no use to others. (Also, don't forget to cite the assistance here when you turn in the assignment. To do otherwise would be academically dishonest.)

Comment: Every time I stumble upon a valid homework question that shows an effort (and this hasn't happened a lot to me), I feel so damn content. Upvoted for the sake of decency.

Comment: @Carlos when I edited the formatting of the question, I realized a '>' that probably belonged to the </head> tag was floating in the middle of the js code, I let it there so that it doesn't break the original code. But it's there

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote strings in your `document.write()` call.

```
document.write("Number Set " +i+ " is " + num + ", " + num1 + ", " +num2 + '<br>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted seems right based on your description save for a couple of minor errors. I have cleaned it up and made it runnable right here in Stack Overflow.

```js
var i, num, n, num1, num2, cnt = 0;
n = 100;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  console.log("Number Set", i, "is", num, num1, num2);
  if (num == 7) {
    cnt++;
  }
}
console.log("<br>Total number of Sevens: " + cnt);
```

**Note:** When you use `+` between a string and a number as you have done, the number will be converted into a string and then the two strings will be appended. Comma (`,`) will append the values separated by spaces. I used commas throughout to make it clear and consistent. I also spaced things out a bit for readability and used `console.log` so we can see the result of the formatting changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with your code:

1) **You are trying to send a string to document.write but have not formatted it correctly**.  Anything that is just a string and not a variable of some kind needs to be enclosed in quotes.  In your case, this includes: 'is' and the commas (',').

(I've put each line within a `<p>` tag to ensure that it gets output to a newline)

2) ***There is also a stray `>` character towards the end of your code which needs to be removed.***

Here's an example of the amended code:

```js
var i,num,n,num1,num2,cnt=0;
n=100;

for( i=1; i<=n; i++){
  num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
  num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
  num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
  
  document.write("<p>Number Set " + i + " is " + num + ", " + num1 + ", " + num2 + "</p>");
  
  if(num == 7){
    cnt++;
  }
}
document.write("<br>Total number of Sevens: " + cnt);
```

Answer (score 1):

you've a couple of problems:

1. the `<head>` element is not closed properly.
2. you've got some syntax errors in most areas.

Consider this illustration below:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Day 3 - Example 7</title>
</head>
<body>

 <script language="javascript">
   // count number of times seven was generated
   var i,num,n,num1,num2,cnt=0;
   n=100;
   for( i=1; i<=n; i++){
    num = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
    num1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
    num2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
    console.log("Number Set " +i + " is --> "+ num +", "+ num1 +" ," +num2);
    if(num == 7){
       cnt++;
     }
   }
   document.write("<br>Total number of Sevens: " + cnt);

 </script>
</body>
</html
```

you can replace the `console.log()` with this is you want:

```
document.write("Number Set " +i+ " is " + num + ", " + num1 + ", " +num2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var n = 100,
    counter = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {                       // repeat this n times
  var text = "Number Set " + i + " is:";             // text of this set
  for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {                       // repeat this 3 times
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;    // get a random number between 0 an 10
    text += (j? ", ": " ") + num;                    // add it to this set's text
    if(num === 7)                                    // if the random number is seven
      counter++;                                     // then increment the counter
  }
  document.write(text + "<br>");                     // show this set's text
}

document.write("Total number of Sevens: " + counter + "<br>"); // the seven's count
```

Comment: How do I add comas to the number sets?

Comment: @Carlos change this: `text += " " + num;` to this: `text += (j? ", ": " ") + num;` (which is if `j != 0` it's `", " + num` otherwise it's `" " + num`)!

Comment: @ ibrahim mahrir great answer but I meant comas to the numbers   1,2,3

Comment: @Carlos Yeah! I had a mistake in the comment! I've update it along with the answer! If you mean something else by _comas to numbers_ then please clarify!

Answer (score 0):

Use this line: `document.write("Number Set "+i+" is "+ num +","+num1 +","+num2);`

Answer (score 0):

Enough commenters have pointed out the erros in the document write - I though I'd just add a version which solves the issue with a little bit more elegance.

```js
var setSize = 3,
    totalSize = 100,
    magicNumber = 7,
    magicCounter = 0,
    i = setSize * totalSize,
    set = [];
    
do {
    // push random number into set
    set.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1));
    
    // decrement the counter
    i -= 1;
   
    // jump to the next iteration, if the set is not complete
    if (set.length !== setSize) {
     continue;
    }
    
    console.log("Number set is", set.join(', '));

    // reduce the array into the sum of items and check if equal 7
    if (set.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0) === magicNumber) {
        magicCounter += 1;
    }
    
    // reset the set for the next line
    set = [];

} while (i > 0);

console.log("Total number of ", magicNumber, ":", magicCounter);
```